# Specify Input Argument with KerasRegressor

Tags: initialization, keras

I use a Keras neural network and I would like the input dimension to be automatically set, not hardcoded like in every tutorial I have seen so far. How could I accomplish this?

My code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
seed = 1

X = df_input
Y = df_res

def baseline_model(x):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()    
    model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=x, kernel_initializer='normal', activation=relu))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model

inpt  = len(X.columns)
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn = baseline_model(inpt  ) , epochs=2, batch_size=1000, verbose=2)
estimator.fit(X,Y)
```

And the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File ipython-input-2-49d765e85d15, line 20, in  estimator.fit(X,Y)
>
> TypeError: **call**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

Comment: This error happens because estimator is not a method that you can call. Concretely, it is an object with a scikit-learn API. That is, you can train your estimator with `estimator.fit(X, Y)`, and make predictions with `estimator.predict(X,Y)`.

Comment: Thank you, and do you have a working solution in mind ?

Comment: Just replace `estimator(X,Y)` by `estimator.fit(X, Y)`.

Comment: Already done and It does not solve the initial problem. It raises an error about `TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs' `

Comment: Could you update your question with the new code?

Comment: Sure ! It's done

Comment: Great! I posted an answer for your problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would wrap your `baseline_model` as follows:

```py
def baseline_model(x):
    def bm():
        # create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=x, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
        # Compile model
        model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
        return model
    return bm
```

And then define and fit the `KerasRegressor` as:

```py
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model(inpt), epochs=2, batch_size=1000, verbose=2)
estimator.fit(X, Y)
```

This avoids having to hardcode the input dimension in `baseline_model`.

Comment: Thank you, I never thought about this solution. I'm not even sure why adding a layer of function make it works.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. The thing here is that `KerasRegressor` expects a callable that builds a model, rather than the model itself. By wrapping your function in this way you can return the build function (without calling it) with a specified `input_dim`.

Answer (score 0):

I try that and works

```python
def create_model(max_features, num_class):
    def bm():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(max_features,)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(Dense(512))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(Dense(num_class, activation='softmax'))
        model.summary()
        model.compile(
            loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics['accuracy'])
        return model
    return bm
```

and then

```python
model_clf = KerasClassifier(
    build_fn=create_model(max_features, num_class), epochs=10, 
    batch_size=32, verbose=2)
history = model_clf.fit(
                X_train, y_train,
                batch_size=32,
                epochs=10,
                verbose=2,
                validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation ony why your solution works? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @ Suit Boy Apps: This has been clearly explained by @rvinas